# "%.2f" is rounding my number up instead of cutting

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode, floating-point

I have the following number

> 7.9775609756097534

and I'm using the code below to only show two decimals

```
let formatted = String(format: "Angle: %.2f", angle)
```

the problem is that the result is:

> 7.98

instead of

> 7.97

Comment: That is what it's intended to do.

Comment: .2f will round up your value to 2 decimal digit

Comment: okay, so how do I cut the number to two decimals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For cases such as yours we use `NumberFormatter`. It is a class designed to do what you need and more. For your case it should be enough to use the following:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.roundingMode = .down
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
numberFormatter.string(from: 1.236)
```

This now locks fraction digits to be exactly 2. By increasing minimum fraction digits more "0" may be appended as in `0.10` may become `0.100`. Maximum fraction digits will simply restrict up to what point the number will be displayed.

There are other options as well such as making `1234567.89` show as `1.234.567,89` which is really nice for users that are used to such formatting.

Answer (score -3):

Alternatively, you can do bit string manipulation

```
let numberInFloat:Float = 7.9775609756097534
let numberInString: String = String(format: "%f", numberInFloat)

let numberParts = numberInString.components(separatedBy: ".")

print(String(format: "Output: %@.%@", String(numberParts[0]), String(numberParts[1].prefix(2))))
```

> Output: 7.97

Comment: Formatting with `%f` rounds, so it can be expected some numbers will be rounded in an undesired way during formatting, after which extracting two digits from the string will not produce the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, can you give an example of such kind so I should test on it?